# SQL COUNT is not returning as numeric. It appears to be returning as string

Tags: sql, sorting, casting

SQL COUNT is not returning as numeric. It appears to be returning as string.

```
SELECT 
    Count (StateProvince)
FROM 
    CUSTOMER
JOIN 
    INVOICE ON CustomerID = FK_CustomerID
GROUP BY 
    StateProvince
ORDER BY 
    StateProvince DESC
```

Then my results are

```
2
1
10
1
1
```

I think the group by is returning a string?  Either way, how do I get the results to be

```
10
2
1
1
1
```

Comment: `order by` count, not the stateprovince

Comment: if you post a complete answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This corrected my issue.

```
SELECT Count (StateProvince) AS "Count"
FROM CUSTOMER
  JOIN INVOICE
    ON CustomerID = FK_CustomerID
GROUP BY StateProvince
ORDER BY Count DESC
```